# Can't read state variable from inside React-Table Column Definition (React.useMemo)

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm using React-Table. There is a column definition that occurs as `React.useMemo` as follows:

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: "approverId",
            accessor: "approverId",
            isVisible: false
        },
        {
            Header: "Assigned Approver",
            accessor: "assignedApproverName",
            isVisible: true,
        },
        // Note this final Action column containing a Button
        {
            Header: "Action",
            accessor: "id",
            isVisible: true,
            disableSortBy: true,
            disableGlobalFilter: true,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
                <div className="table-button-wrapper">
                    
                    <Button onClick={() => setVars(cell.row.values,'edit')} variant="primary" size="sm" className="btn-slim" title="Edit" data-tip='Edit'><i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></Button>
                
                </div>
            )
        }],
```

The last Action column defines a Button which should call a component function, `setVars`, on `onClick`. When I get to that function, I have some state variables (all within the same component) that I need to examine, but they are NULL inside that function (which they should **not** be).

```
const [approverList, setApproverList] = useState(null);
// approverList is set on useEffect([]) correctly upon initialization, 
// verified (printed its contents in component)

function setVars(values, mode) {
    // This state var. should not be NULL, but is NULL when called from the React-Table column
    if (approverList != null) {
        //...
    }
}
```

I verified in the debugger that:

1. `approverList` is not NULL, and filled out in the component, before the button is clicked
2. the issue has to do with this React-Table memo, everywhere else the variable is read fine

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that the second argument inside of useMemo is keeping track of the changing state.  So if you are seeing a change in the approverList state, you have to use the following column definition:

```
    const columns = useMemo(()=>[
        {
            Header: "approverId",
            accessor: "approverId",
            isVisible: false
        },
        {
            Header: "Assigned Approver",
            accessor: "assignedApproverName",
            isVisible: true,
        },
        // Note this final Action column containing a Button
        {
            Header: "Action",
            accessor: "id",
            isVisible: true,
            disableSortBy: true,
            disableGlobalFilter: true,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
                <div className="table-button-wrapper">
                    
                    <Button onClick={() => setVars(cell.row.values,'edit')} variant="primary" size="sm" className="btn-slim" title="Edit" data-tip='Edit'><i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></Button>
                
                </div>
            )
        }]

, [approverList])
```

Comment: I used useMemo but still not able to access the state

Comment: Note that react-table has upgraded and is now called TanStack v8.  Also make sure that you have set the variable to be tracked with useState() hook.

Comment: Ya, I am using the upgraded version and variable is set through useState(). Also, tried to set the variables in parent and passed them as props to the table component, but still it is null

Answer (score -1):

you have to make CustomCell Component

```
{
        Header: "Action",
        accessor: "id",
        isVisible: true,
        disableSortBy: true,
        disableGlobalFilter: true,
        Cell: ({ cell }) =><CustomCell cell={cell}/>
    }
```

```
export const CustomCell = (cell)=>{
const [vars , setVars ] = useStats<any>(null)
return (
    <div className="table-button-wrapper">
                    
        <Button onClick={() => setVars(cell.row.values,'edit')} variant="primary" size="sm" className="btn-slim" title="Edit" data-tip='Edit'><i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></Button>
    
    </div>
)

}
```